# How to make a request to get a picture from an ipcam?

Tags: python, request

I have some troubles getting the picture on my ip camera on python. I have an axis camera, I almost do the work on the rtsp link and cv2 video capture but when the hours go by I got an h264 error ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68667218) I asked for that problem).

So I decided to use a get request to get the picture, but now I got 401, error. Here is my code:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
r = requests.get("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/jpg/image.jpg", auth=HTTPBasicAuth('xxx', 'xxx'))
print(r.status_code)
```

I also tried with out the HTTPBasicAuth but the same, I don't know how to  get a good auth here.

Any help?

Comment: You need to be authenticated first.

Comment: bedore the r = request.get? how can i do this?

Comment: actually i solve it w/ HTTPDigestAuth

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. I have done the same code and works fine on my side. I would suggest you to verify the credentials that you have provided as a 401 response code is received when you provide wrong password or username.
Additionally, don't forget to pass the `stream=True` parameter inside the requests.get parameter otherwise the process will never successfully return anything even if the credentials actually work.

```
    import requests
    from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
    r = requests.get("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/jpg/image.jpg", auth=HTTPBasicAuth('xxx', 'xxx'), stream=True)
    
    for streamDataChunks in r:
        process_raw_image_data(streamDataChunks)
```